# Как правильно подключить стиля в Meteor

Tags: meteor

Как правильно добавлять стиля в приложении? Если обычной автозагрузкой, тогда наш файл подключается через тег  и кешируется. Если через import, тогда стиля добавляются в тег , что в свою очередь означает, что стиля не кешируются. Но сайт разделен на две части: пользовательская и админка, и не хотелось загружать стиля из админку для обычных пользователей. Как быть в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

На англоязычном SO предлагают использовать вариант использования пакета [mrt:external-file-loader](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/external-file-loader).
Пример:

```
Template.myCustomTemplate.created = function() {
  Meteor.Loader.loadCss("//example.com/myCSS/style.css");
};
```

[Ссылка на оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694517/3363492)